# Get back HTML code from json encoded string

Tags: php, android, html, json

We are trying to get some HTML source code using an API written in PHP. The PHP code uses `json_encode` to encode the response and then echoes it. The response we receive is similar to this.

```
{"status":true,"message":"Form fetched.","html":"
<!DOCTYPE html>\n\n
<html>\n\n
    <head>\n\n<\/head>\n\n
        <body onload=\"document.form.submit()\">\n\n\t
            <div>\n\t\t\t
                <img src='https:\/\/www.example.com\/resource\/images\/loader.gif' width='300px' height='300px'\/>\n\t\t\tPlease wait while we redirect you...\n\t<\/div>\n\n\t
                <form name='form' method='POST' action='https:\/\/test.test.com\/_payment'>\n\t\t
                    <input type='hidden' name='key' value='randomFFx'>\n\t\t
                    <input type='hidden' name='txnid' value='YHOOCH31DG90HeQpc8h7'>\n\t\t
                    <input type='hidden' name='productinfo' value='Adding to user.'>\n\t\t
                    <input type='hidden' name='amount' value='100'>\n\t\t
                    <input type='hidden' name='firstname' value='test'>\n\t\t
                    <input type='hidden' name='lastname' value='test'>\n\t\t
                    <input type='hidden' name='email' value='support@example.com'>\n\t\t
<\/form>\n<\/body>\n<\/html>"}
```

How do I get a proper HTML code without `\n\t` which I can show in the webview. Currently due to these, the form isn't getting submitted automatically. We have tried replacing `\n`, `\t`, `\` with , but is there a better method to retrieve the HTML code. Thanks in advance for all your help and suggestions.

Comment: If you control the API it would probably be better to strip those whitespace chars before the API sends the response. How do you obtain the HTML?

Comment: Is this an Android or PHP question?

Comment: @marekful but still the `/`s would be protected. And there might be a better approach.

Comment: @KNeerajLal Someone who writes APIs in PHP can also help, so it is also related to PHP, I guess.

Comment: Could you show how you are loading the data into the `WebView`?

Comment: @KNeerajLal Sure, will add that too

Comment: Are you trying to process this JSON in javascript or PHP or JAVA

Comment: Android @RiggsFolly I am creating the API.